Spring-web / Jakarta-servlet: detect input-change in 'when' function
In my .jsp-file, I have a text-field and a button. Both elements are part of a table. The table is filled through a forEach loop, which iterates over a List<WordDto> from the java-controller. Each WordDto has its own text-field and button.
The button of a WordDto should be active, if at least one of the two following conditions are met:

A boolean in the WordDto is false
The content in the text-field does not match a String in the WordDto (Initially, the text-field is filled with that String

My current code:
<body>
<div class="container">
    <%--@elvariable id="languageName" type="java.lang.String"--%>
    <h1>Generated words with '${languageName}'</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Word</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <%--@elvariable id="words" type="java.util.List"--%>
        <c:forEach items="${words}" var="singleWord" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <form:form method="post" action="word">
                    <input type="hidden" name="listIndex" value="${singleWord.listIndex}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="languageId" value="${singleWord.languageId}"/>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input onchange="updateSaveState(singleWord, word.value)" type="text" name="word" value="${singleWord.word}"/>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${singleWord.savedInDb}">
                                <label>Saved</label>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Save"/>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>
                </form:form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="generate" class="btn">Generate new words in this language</a>
</div>
<script>
    function updateSaveState(wordDto, text) {
        console.log(text)
        if(wordDto.word !== text)
            wordDto.savedInDb = false;
    }
</script>
</body>

As you can see, I tried to use onChange on the text-field to check, if the text was different. But this way I get the console error: singleWord is not defined. I also tried with onChange=${singleWord.savedInDb = false}, but then the boolean is never true, even when the texts are equal.
How can I disable the button, when the boolean is true AND the text-field is not changed?
